# Refactoring: Very similar switch cases

Tags: c, refactoring

I have several `struct` declared which contain different data. I also have an `enum` that corresponds to those structures. There are several places in my code where I need to access information about the structures and I'm doing it via the enum. This results in few `switch` statements that return this information.

I've enclosed those `switch` statements in their own functions in order to re-use wherever possible. This resulted in three functions that look very similar.

Example psuedo-code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int varA;
char varB;
} A;

typedef struct
{
     int varA;
     int varB;
     int varC;
} B;

typedef struct
{
     int varA;
     short varB;
} C;

typedef enum { structA, structB, structC } STRUCT_ENUM;

int returnSize(STRUCT_ENUM structType)
{
     int retVal = 0;
     switch(structType)
     {
          case structA:
               retVal = sizeof(A);
               break;
          case structB:
               retVal = sizeof(B);
               break;
          case structC:
               retVal = sizeof(C);
               break;
          default:
               break;
      }

      return retVal;
}

void printStructName(STRUCT_ENUM structType)
{
     switch(structType)
     {
          case structA:
               printf("Struct: A\r\n");
               break;
          case structB:
               printf("Struct: B\r\n");
               break;
          case structC:
               printf("Struct: C\r\n");
               break;
          default:
               break;
      }
}

void createDataString(STRUCT_ENUM structType, char* output, unsigned char* input)
{
     switch(structType)
     {
          case structA:
          {
               A a = *(A*)input;
               sprintf(output, "data: %d, %d", a.varA, a.varB);
               break;
          }
          case structB:
          {
               B b = *(B*)input;
               sprintf(output, "data: %d, %d, %d", b.varA, b.varB, b.varC);
               break;
          }
          case structC:
          {
               C c = *(C*)input;
               sprintf(output, "data: %d, %d", c.varA, c.varB);
               break;
          }
          default:
               break;
      }
}

int main(void) {
    char foobar[50];

    printf("Return size: %d\r\n", returnSize(structA));
    printStructName(structB);

    C c = { 10, 20 };
    createDataString(structC, foobar, (unsigned char*) &c);
    printf("Data string: %s\r\n", foobar);

    return 0;
}
```

Those free functions basically contain the same `switch` with different code placed in the cases. With this setup, adding new struct and enum value results in three places in the code that needs changing.

The question is: is there a way to refactor this into something more maintainable? Additional constraint is that the code is written in C.

EDIT: online example: http://ideone.com/xhXmXu

Comment: This does not compile in C. What are `A`, `B` and `C`? These names are not declared. And C does have "objects" actually.

Comment: @Olaf Its just pseudo code to show the idea, not the entire code. How does C have objects when there are no classes?

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.15 And you can also do OOP in C.

Comment: @Olaf Edited the question and added working implementation. The question was more theoretical though.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use static arrays and use `STRUCT_ENUM` as the index. Given the nature of your functions, I don't really know if you would consider it more maintainable, but it's an alternative I usually prefer, examples for names and sizes:

```
typedef enum { structA, structB, structC, STRUCT_ENUM_MAX } STRUCT_ENUM;
char *struct_name[STRUCT_ENUM_MAX] = {[structA] = "Struct A", [structB] = "Struct B", [structC] = "Struct C"};
size_t struct_size[STRUCT_ENUM_MAX] = {[structA] = sizeof(A), [structB] = sizeof(B), [structC] = sizeof(C)};
```

for printing content you can keep a similar array of functions receiving a `void *` that will print the value of this argument.

**Edit:**
Added designated initializers as per Jen Gustedt's comment.

Comment: Could make this approach even more explicit by using *designated intializers such as `= { [structA] = "Struct A", .... }`.

Comment: @JensGustedt yep, quite a good idea, just one note about that is that such code won't compile as C++.

Comment: Yes, right, but in C++ you would do these things quite differently, anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it into a single function and a single switch, with an additional parameter. Like so

```
int enumInfo(STRUCT_ENUM structType, int type) // 1 = returnSize 2 = printStructName
{
     int retVal = 0;
     switch(structType)
     {
          case structA:
               If ( type == 1 ) { retVal = sizeof(A); }
               else { printf("Struct: A"); }
               break;
          case structB:
               If ( type == 1 ) { retVal = sizeof(B); }
               else { printf("Struct: B"); }
               break;
          case structC:
               If ( type == 1 ) { retVal = sizeof(C); }
               else { printf("Struct: C"); }
               break;
          default:
               break;
      }

  return retVal;

}
```